# Nativescript unit testing shows no reachable hosts

Tags: unit-testing, nativescript

I'm trying to [follow this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/04/unit-testing-in-telerik-nativescript-mobile-app/) to do unit testing in Nativescript with Jasmine/Karma. When I do tns test android, my phone flashes that the test ran succesfully for about a second, but then goes to a blue screen with the nativescript logo that says "no reachable hosts".

Here is the console log:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL                                                                                                                                                             

Total time: 10.693 secs                                                                                                                                                      
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-unit-test-runner for android.                                                                                                      
Project successfully prepared (android)                                                                                                                                      
Executing after-prepare hook from D:\npn\natures-notebook-mobile\hooks\after-prepare\nativescript-unit-test-runner.js                                                        
Transferring project files...                                                                                                                                                
Successfully transferred all files.                                                                                                                                          
Applying changes...                                                                                                                                                          
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.naturesnotebookmobile on device TA9921AOKU.                                                                                 
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://myip:9876/context.json                                                                                                                  
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://127.0.0.1:9876/context.json                                                                                                                       
JS: NSUTR: found karma at myip                                                                                                                                     
JS: NSUTR: connecting to karma at http://myip:9876                                                                                                                 
JS: NSUTR: successfully connected to karma           
24 10 2016 09:43:00.395:INFO [NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096)]: Connected on socket /#lsfwgpODsqXMa1AVAAAA with id NativeScriptUnit-5970                                     
JS: NSUTR: downloading http://myip:9876/context.json                                                                                                               
JS: NSUTR: disregarding second execution                                                                                                                                     
JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d                                                  
JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e                                                                 
JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7975a273517f1eb29d7bd018790fd4c7b9a485d5                                                              
JS: NSUTR: require script /base/app/tests/example.js?d4cad4cd203df70666c986cd09ce402b21d89b39 from ../../tests/example.js                                                    
JS: NSUTR: beginning test run                                                                                                                                                
JS: NSUTR: completed test run.                                                                                                                                               
NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.111 secs / 0.01 secs)                                                                                            
JS: NSUTR: completeAck                                                                                                                                                       
JS: NSUTR-socket.io: io server disconnect                                                                                                                                    
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://myip:9876/context.json       
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://127.0.0.1:9876/context.json                                                                                                                       
I/art     (16936): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>                                 
I/art     (16936): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>                                 
I/art     (16936): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>                                     
I/art     (16936): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
```

Any ideas why this would be? tns info:

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-ios          │                 │ 2.3.0          │ Not installed
```

**MORE INFO -** 
When I run tns test android --watch and start up the app on the phone I get this log.

```
NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.083 secs / 0.006 secs)                                                                                           
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://128.196.232.91:9876/context.json                                                                                                                  
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://10.142.143.93:9876/context.json                                                                                                                   
JS: NSUTR: fetching http://127.0.0.1:9876/context.json                                                                                                                       
JS: NSUTR: found karma at 128.196.232.91                                                                                                                                     
JS: NSUTR: connecting to karma at http://128.196.232.91:9876                                                                                                                 
JS: NSUTR: successfully connected to karma                                                                                                                                   
24 10 2016 15:54:26.854:INFO [NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096)]: Connected on socket /#8bujUTl6BGLrcHa7AAAC with id NativeScriptUnit-55                                       
JS: NSUTR: downloading http://128.196.232.91:9876/context.json                                                                                                               
JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d                                                  
JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e                                                                 
JS: NSUTR: eval script /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?7975a273517f1eb29d7bd018790fd4c7b9a485d5                                                              
JS: NSUTR: require script /base/app/tests/example.js?d4cad4cd203df70666c986cd09ce402b21d89b39 from ../../tests/example.js                                                    
JS: NSUTR: beginning test run                                                                                                                                                
JS: NSUTR: completed test run.                                                                                                                                               
NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.099 secs / 0.007 secs)                                                                                           
JS: NSUTR: completeAck                                                                                                                                                       
NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096) ERROR                                                                                                                                        
  Disconnectedundefined                                                                                                                                                      
NativeScript / 22 (5.1; XT1096): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.099 secs / 0.007 secs)
```

The app only flashes open showing the test results and then closes right away.

Comment: not sure whats `myip` what is but `http://127.0.0.1:9876/context.json` points to mobile not existent thing, as on mobile you don't have server so change 127.0.0.1 to ip of pc or some server

Comment: myip is the ip of the dev machine not the phone. I pasted a second log to clarify.

Comment: check whether the device has been connected to the PC properly using `adb devices` or `tns device` and verify the status of the device.

Comment: @nikolay I did check and the device is available. I can run the app with no problem. I'm pretty sure the error is specific to the nativescript karma integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is an open [bug](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2119).